# Significance of numeric parameter in SQL COUNT function

Tags: sql, ms-access

Very new to SQL programming! My company uses MS Access and uses SQL queries like the following:

`SELECT RepeatOrder, COUNT(1) FROM [Archive Orders] GROUP BY RepeatOrder`

Whenever the `COUNT` function is used, it is always `COUNT(1)` and nothing else. I've tested the above query with `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(27)` and even `COUNT(-1)`, and they all return exactly the same data.

The [w3schools tutorial on SQL COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) only mentions `COUNT(*)` as an example (when not using a field name).

What is the significance of a number like "1" in a `COUNT` function?

Answer (score 2):

They are all the same.  `COUNT(<expression>)` counts the number of non-NULL values of the expression.  And `1` and `-1` and `27` and `3.1415916535` are all equally not `NULL`.

The standard is `COUNT(*)`.  For some reason, some people are under the mistaken impression that this is not the fastest or best method to just count everything.  But it is.

I should note that this is equivalent to `SUM(1)` . . . with one exception.  In a correlated subquery that filters out all rows, this would return `NULL` whereas `COUNT(*)` (or `COUNT(1)` would return `0`.